# page flip without button click

Tags: iphone

I need smooth page curling for my ebook without clicking any button just like in PageCurl demo. But in that code they are using a pdf file(CGPDFDocumentRef). And am using a xml file for my ebook. How can i implement this? i tried to do but no use. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2):

You should start by reading the basic documentation and doing some google searches, then when you have specific issues about implementing things in the docs, or questions related to understanding how to apply something in the docs, you should come and ask those specific questions.

You can also start by accepting some answers on Stack Overflow for some of the previous questions you've asked.

To get you started, take a look at [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and make sure you read the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)